# Insert a customized series as a new column in a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series, boolean-indexing

Given this DataFrame with columns: `category`, `Year`, and `Profit`

[image]

```
data = {'category':pd.Series(['A','A','A','A','A','A']),
        'Year':pd.Series([1,1,3,3,3,4]),
        'Profit':pd.Series([10,11,5,6,30,31])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

how can I insert numbers creating a new column `Numbering` **by the following rule** without manually enter the numbers one-by-one:

1. Insert `0` for the corresponding `Year < 3`.
2. Insert `1` at the **first** cell with `Year >= 3`.
3. **After that** insert a geometric series with a common ratio of `0.5` for the corresponding `Year >= 3`.

The desire output is displayed as follows:

[image]

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Also, please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC Thanks for the advice, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `cumsum`

```
s = (0.5**(df.Year.ge(3).cumsum()-1)).mask(df.Year<3,0)
Out[15]: 
0    0.000
1    0.000
2    1.000
3    0.500
4    0.250
5    0.125
Name: Year, dtype: float64
df['numbering'] = s
```